# How to apply autocomplete to the dropdown list in excel using c#?

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, vba

I have a list with name mydropdown which has around 150 values,so i it annoying for user to drag the list and select the item.I searched for autocomplete list for excel and find that combobox can be used but all the processing is done using macro and i cant use macro in my project,i m using c# vsto so is there way to handel combobox using c# or is there a workaround?

thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0):

The combo box from the Control Toolbox toolbar has this feature. Set its MatchEntry property to 0 - fmMatchEntryFirstLetter or 1 - fmMatchEntryComplete (the default value).